# Get current authenticated user from all other microservices

Tags: spring, spring-security, microservices

I am creating a project with microservices architecture using spring. I have zuul for centralized security management, and some other microservices.
To access current authenticated user, in zuul i use this line of code :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
```

But to get the user from other microservices, i extract the token (jwt) from the header in each request, and then i extract user info from the claims, but i find this method is a little annoying.
So, is there another more pretty method?
I tried to add the dependencies of spring security in the other microservices to use :

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication
```

but every time i execute a request through zuul, even if the authentication is done from there, i get an unauthorized error message, despite having disabled the security autoconfiguration from these microservices.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for this question? I'm in the same situation. I found this https://medium.com/@Baimurzin/how-to-get-the-current-user-in-spring-cloud-microservices-c876e1c6fc65 but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication won't work in other microservices until you set the principal object in the Spring SecurityContext.

I don't know why you are setting the principal in security context at Zuul and extracting the same there, But yes Authentication and token validation should be done at Zuul and same jwt should be sent to backend microservices in header.
Now in backend microservices, By using spring security, extract the required claims from jwt and put in the SecurityContextHolder once, So that you can utilize it further for request authorizations or method level authorizations too.